# Exported FBX version of a model has over an order of magnitude more polygons

Tags: export, .fbx, polycount

This problem seems fairly simple, but I'm a noob to Blender and I have no idea how to fix it. Basically, I have [this model](https://www.filefaucet.tk/file/?code=B1MnjYzi) which displays this in the bottom-right of Blender 2.8:

[image: Verts Edges Faces Tris etc display in Blender 18510 tris]

However, when I export the model to FBX, and try to use the model in Unity, it seems that the number of polygons has absolutely exploded, as it's over 30 times what appeared in Blender. This is what is displayed in the VRChat SDK:

[image: Unity VRChat SDK polygons display 599008 polygons]

So, what's going on? What's causing the amount of polygons in Unity to be vastly higher than the amount of tris in Blender? Is there some kind of automated smoothing when exporting, if so how can I stop it? The model's fidelity when displayed in Blender with 18,510 tris is plenty good enough.

Comment: Just remove the solidify and subdivision surface modifiers. You can find them in the  properties panel (right side of the screen).

Comment: Is it "Subdivisions" -> "Render" and "Viewport" and "Quality"? What should I set them to, one? Or do I click the X?

Comment: Viewport will be exported. Set it to 0 or click on the X. Or you can disable the modifier export in the fbx exporter under the geometry tab.